# Catching DatabaseException in Flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I wanted to know how I can handle and succesfully catch my Database Exception. I had a primary key ID and another key called name in my Sqlite database. Im using the flutter plugin sqflite. I wanted to handle the case when there is already a entry in my database with the given ID i want to display ID already exists, for that I want to know how I can handle the exceptions.

I tried to surround the code in a try catch block but Im not able to make FLutter realize about the DatabaseException class, it gives me error saying "DatabaseException" isn't a type and can't be used in on catch clause. I want to add a new Subject into my database after a button is pressed and if user enters the same ID value as already existing one I want to handle the error.

```
onSubmitted: (test) async {
                      Subject newSubject = Subject(name: name, id: test);
                      try {
                        await DBProvider.db.newSubject(newSubject);
                      } on DatabaseException {}
                    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `sqflite` in the dart file where you're using the exception, add 
this:

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
```